# angular js and html arrangement

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

this is very absurd issue.

i am trying to populate a select control with ng-repeat (i am not using ng-options for a reson),

when my html looks like that:

```
<option ng-repeat="m in appData">{{m.somthing}}</option>
```

the resault comes out fine.

but when i rearange the html to this:

```
<option ng-repeat="m in appData">
{{m.somthing}}
</option>
```

i get a '**\n** ' added to the value of the option which reprisent the line break;

WTH??

any ideas?

thanks in advanced

Comment: because there is a linebreak in your second piece of code between option tag and m.somthing ?

Comment: i know that. but my question is why?
if i put <option>non angular value</option> it not happening

Comment: i found a solutuion
<option ng-repeat="m in appData" value="{{m.somthing}}">{{m.somthing}}</option>


so stupid of me to even bother with question

Comment: glad you did, put your answer below for other people who can gain from it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solutuion

```
 <option ng-repeat="m in appData" value="{{m.somthing}}">
    {{m.somthing}}
 </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.html**
1.
    
    {{ x }}

2.

```
<option ng-repeat="x in names">
  {{ x }}
</option>
```

It does not make any difference.The output for both the syntax is same.The output will take line break "\n" for both cases.